# setter of useState don't care about await

Tags: reactjs

I have an asynchronicity problem due to the useState Hook.
Indeed, the latter seems to not take the await into consideration at all, as if the setter was asynchronous. I would have liked to know if someone would have a solution to solve my problem?

```js
const [checkedList, setCheckedList] = useState([]);

const onCheckChange = async(checkedValues) => {
        await setCheckedList(checkedValues);
        await onFinish(checkedList);

    }
```

Thank you

Comment: you need a `useEffect` with `checkedList` as dependency

Comment: Could you bring more information about your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using useEffect hook:

```
const [checkedList, setCheckedList] = useState([]);
    
    const onCheckChange = (checkedValues) => {
           setCheckedList(checkedValues);
        }
    
    useEffect(() => {
       onFinish(checkedList);
    }, [checkedList]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. 
So useEffect is the best way to handle this kind of asynchronous problem?

Comment: useEffect is used to handle life cycle methods in functional components, we can handle these kind of problems through useEffect, when the dependency change it will render accordingly.. More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html  & https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/react-hooks-how-to-use-useeffect-ecea3e90d84f

Comment: if this helps then kindly upvote this solution..thank you :)

Comment: @bakar_dev Why would you like to listen to changes for `checkedList ` when you have a direct trigger ? Isn't is just over-engineering ?

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use the same argument that you're getting in the function.

```js
const [checkedList, setCheckedList] = useState([]);

const onCheckChange = async(checkedValues) => {
        await setCheckedList(checkedValues);
        //await onFinish(checkedList);
        await onFinish(checkedValues);
}
```